# Java BufferedReader arabic text file problem

Tags: java, character-encoding, arabic, text-files, bufferedinputstream

Problem: Arabic words in my text files read by java show as series of question marks : ??????

Here is the code:

```
        File[] fileList = mainFolder.listFiles();
        BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
        Reader reader = null;


        try{

        for(File f : fileList){           
            reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f.getPath()), "UTF8");
            bufferReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line = null;

            while((line = bufferReader.readLine())!= null){
               System.out.println(new String(line.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
            }              

        }
        }
        catch(Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            //Close the BufferedReader
            try {
                if (bufferReader != null)
                    bufferReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

As you can see I have specified the UTF-8 encoding in different places and still I get question marks, do you have any idea how can I fix this??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
System.out.println(new String(line.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
```

by

```
System.out.println(line);
```

The [`String#getBytes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) without the charset argument namely uses platform default encoding to get the bytes from the string, which may not be UTF-8 per se. You're already reading the bytes as UTF-8 by `InputStreamReader`, so you don't need to massage it forth and back afterwards.

Further, ensure that your display console (where you're reading those lines) supports UTF-8. In for example Eclipse, you can do that by *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding > Other > UTF-8*.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: I had this and It still displayed ????. However how do I make sure the console supports UTF-8? I'm pretty sure my console has support for utf-8 since I was able to print some arabic text on it from another project from the mySQL database.

Comment: Depends on the kind of console. I added an example for Eclipse. It will however still fail when you massage the bytes forth and back using the default encoding as you did in your initial code.

Comment: do you know how can I do this in netbeans? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I haven't touched Netbeans for years. Look around in its manual (F1?) using keyword "encoding". To exclude the one or other, does it display properly when you do `System.out.println("somearabic")` directly?

Comment: Yes It does display properly when I do System.out.println("arabic stuff"). Can the problem be in the notepad or the txt file encoding itself?? is that possible?

Comment: Is the file itself saved as UTF-8? In Notepad you can specify that in some dropdown below the file name field on *Save As*. Otherwise please post a small snippet of arabic text and the byte numbers of the byte array which you got when you read it by `InputStream`, then we can determine if it has properly been decoded.

Comment: Thanks. That was it , It was notepad, I didn't notice the encoding there!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to print out the line directly, print out the Unicode values of each character. For example:

```
char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i + ": " + chars[i] + " - " + (int) chars[i]);
}
```

Then look up the relevant characters in the [Unicode code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/).

If you find it's printing 63, then those really *are* question marks... which would suggest that your text file isn't truly UTF-8 to start with.

If, on the other hand for some characters it's printing out "?" but then a value other than 63, then that would suggest it's a console display issue and you're reading the data correctly.

Comment: I agree, first separate the encoding issue from the display issue